# Linux lock ordering about zone->lock & inode->lock

Tags: linux, memory, locking

I want to block all the memory

so I overlaped zone's lock and inode's lock like this

```
struct zone *node_zones = &NODE_DATA(0)->node_zones;
for(zone = node_zones; zone - node_zones < MAX_NR_ZONES; zone++){
   if(!populated_zone(zone)) continue;
   spin_lock(&zone->lock);
   list_for_each(curr, &zone->lruvec.lists[LRU_INACTIVE_FILE]){

      clean_page = list_entry(curr, struct page, lru);
      mutex_lock(&clean_page->mapping->host->i_mutex);


         .....
      mutex_unlock(&clean_page->mapping->host->i_mutex);
   }
   spin_unlock(&zone->lock);
```

But when I executed this source code,

I got a dead lock. I think it's about lock ordering but I don't know exactly and how to solve.

Could somebody help me?